# link to profile in menu

Tags: 7, theming, routes

I am using the default profile as a "user dashboard" I have a main navigation link that needs to link to the users profile so is there a way to insert a dynamic link based on the current user? I need to add something like

```
user/{$GLOBALS['user']->uid}
```

If there anyway of accomplishing something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the link directly as `/user`. It also goes to the profile page which is similar to the `/user/{$GLOBALS['user']->uid}`

Now if you want user id also with it, e.g profile in `edit mode (user/10/edit)` then you need to add [Menu Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link) module. It provides  you option to use Token to make the link dynamic for every user profile instead of static path.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tokens to create a menu link with this path: `user/[current-user:uid]/edit`.